# php undefined index in drowdown list value

Tags: php, html, forms, post

guys!
Have some issue with php parsing.
Here is the code:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="transactions">
<select name= "cat" class="cs-select cs-skin-border">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
                <option value="Aviabileti">Aviatickets</option>
                <option value="Oteli">Hotel</option>
                <option value="Krasota">Beauty</option>
                <option value="Odezhda_obyv">Clothes</option>
                <option value="Razvlecheniya">Amusement</option>
                <option value="Restorani">Restaurant</option>
                <option value="Telekom">Telecom</option>
                <option value="Toplivo">Fuel</option>
                <option value="ZhD_bileti">Railway tickets</option>
                <option value="Tyragenstva">Travel agencies</option>
                <option value="Dom_remont">House and repair</option>
                <option value="Foto_video">Foto and video</option>
</select>   
<input name="pointsinput" type="text">
<input type="text" name="destination">
<input type="text" name="cost">
 <label>
 <input type="Submit" name="submit" style="visibility:hidden"><span><
 img name = "gobut" src="go.png"></span>
 </label>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$trans=$_POST['transactions'];
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$points = $_POST['pointsinput'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$cost=$_POST['cost'];
echo $cat;
echo $destination;
echo $points;
echo $cost;
echo $trans;
}
?>
```

A have php error: "Undefined index cat in ...",but all of other vars are display correct.
If I set my dropdown list in first place,and then all of my input forms,it works correct
What's the matter?

Comment: Does your `echo $cat` display something ?

Comment: But I select it in my html page

Comment: @Erlaunis He's getting the error on the line that assigns to `$cat`.

Comment: @Barmar Ok, I didn't see the assignation

Comment: @Erlaunis Did you read the error message? it says "undefined index", not "undefined variable".

Comment: @Barmar,Yeap!You're right!

Comment: @Barmar That's why I asked it ! No matter

Comment: Guys,the problem was it css. I used css file to make my select form looks better,i disabled it and the code works correctly! Thanks for help everybody!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line :-

```
<option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
```

To

```
<option value="">Select category</option>
```

For disable use this :-

```
<select name="cat" class="cs-select cs-skin-border" disabled>
```

Try this code :-

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="transactions">
<select name="cat" class="cs-select cs-skin-border">
                <option value="">Select category</option>
                <option value="Aviabileti">Aviatickets</option>
                <option value="Oteli">Hotel</option>
                <option value="Krasota">Beauty</option>
                <option value="Odezhda_obyv">Clothes</option>
                <option value="Razvlecheniya">Amusement</option>
                <option value="Restorani">Restaurant</option>
                <option value="Telekom">Telecom</option>
                <option value="Toplivo">Fuel</option>
                <option value="ZhD_bileti">Railway tickets</option>
                <option value="Tyragenstva">Travel agencies</option>
                <option value="Dom_remont">House and repair</option>
                <option value="Foto_video">Foto and video</option>
</select>   
<input name="pointsinput" type="text">
<input type="text" name="destination">
<input type="text" name="cost">
 <label>
 <input type="Submit" name="submit" style="visibility:hidden"><span>
 <img name = "gobut" src="go.png"></span>
 </label>
</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
//print_r($_POST);//die;
$trans=$_POST['transactions'];
if(!empty($_POST['cat'])){
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
}else{
 $cat="category not select";       
}
$points = $_POST['pointsinput'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$cost=$_POST['cost'];
echo $cat."<br>";
echo $destination."<br>";
echo $points."<br>";
echo $cost."<br>";
echo $trans."<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: if(!empty($_POST['cat'])){
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
}else{
 $cat="category disabled";       
}

Comment: try this @DaniilGurin

Comment: Rahautos,i have category disabled string

Comment: Rahautos,i select it on web-page but it's not selected-that's issue

Answer (score 0):

Remove disabled attribute this line. As it is disabling selectbox.
So, Replace.

```
 <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
```

with

```
 <option value="" selected>Select category</option>
```

Comment: Why? It's normal to have a prompt option like this in dropdown menus. Maybe he should just remove the `disabled` attribute.

Comment: @DaniilGurin Please check my updated answer, Also let me know your exact requirement.

Comment: @sandeepsure I need just to put all values from my input forms and select  form to php variables to further work with it

Comment: @sandeepsure did you notice,that i said about location?

Comment: @sandeepsure It works when select form is the first from all of input forms

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce this. You do have a type around `<img`. There's a link return between `<` and `img`.

Here's where I attempted to reproduce it: http://viper-7.com/qgWXvN

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="transactions">
<select name="cat" id="cat" class="cs-select cs-skin-border">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
                <option value="Aviabileti">Aviatickets</option>
                <option value="Oteli">Hotel</option>
                <option value="Krasota">Beauty</option>
                <option value="Odezhda_obyv">Clothes</option>
                <option value="Razvlecheniya">Amusement</option>
                <option value="Restorani">Restaurant</option>
                <option value="Telekom">Telecom</option>
                <option value="Toplivo">Fuel</option>
                <option value="ZhD_bileti">Railway tickets</option>
                <option value="Tyragenstva">Travel agencies</option>
                <option value="Dom_remont">House and repair</option>
                <option value="Foto_video">Foto and video</option>
</select>   
<input name="pointsinput" type="text">
<input type="text" name="destination">
<input type="text" name="cost">
 <label>
 <input type="Submit" name="submit" style="visibility:hidden"><span onclick="return checkCat();">
 <img name = "gobut" src="go.png"></span>
 </label>
</form>

<script>
function checkCat() {
var oS = document.getElementById("cat");
if (oS.options[oS.selectedIndex].value == "") {
    alert('CAT EMPTY PLEASE SELECT');
    return false;
}
}
</script>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$trans=$_POST['transactions'];
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$points = $_POST['pointsinput'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$cost=$_POST['cost'];
echo $cat;
echo $destination;
echo $points;
echo $cost;
echo $trans;
}
?>
```

This should solve your issue

Comment: MuthaFury,i select it on my html page,but it doesnt work(

Comment: if you want a dirty solution, you can just put `<?php error_reporting(0);`

Comment: if this solves your problem, please tick the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine. I tested it.

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<input type="text" name="transactions">

<input name="pointsinput" type="text">
<input type="text" name="destination">
<input type="text" name="cost">
 <select name= "cat" class="cs-select cs-skin-border">
                <option value="" disabled selected>Select category</option>
                <option value="Aviabileti">Aviatickets</option>
                <option value="Oteli">Hotel</option>
                <option value="Krasota">Beauty</option>
                <option value="Odezhda_obyv">Clothes</option>
                <option value="Razvlecheniya">Amusement</option>
                <option value="Restorani">Restaurant</option>
                <option value="Telekom">Telecom</option>
                <option value="Toplivo">Fuel</option>
                <option value="ZhD_bileti">Railway tickets</option>
                <option value="Tyragenstva">Travel agencies</option>
                <option value="Dom_remont">House and repair</option>
                <option value="Foto_video">Foto and video</option>
</select>  
 <label>
 <input type="Submit" name="submit" ><span>
 <img name = "gobut" src="go.png"></span>
 </label>

</form>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
$trans=$_POST['transactions'];
$cat=$_POST['cat'];
$points = $_POST['pointsinput'];
$destination = $_POST['destination'];
$cost=$_POST['cost'];
echo $cat;
echo $destination;
echo $points;
echo $cost;
}
?>
```